# checking for errors in ajax file upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, error-handling

i am trying to upload multiple images with php with ajax by submitting the form to an iframe. at the same time i want to upload some text to database about that image.

this one to upload images

```
if($(upload_form_id).submit()){
            alert('ya');
        }
        else{
            alert('no');
        }
```

this post request to save some text value

```
$.getJSON("./ajax_funcs.php?func=save_res_content_fn",{res_box_textarea_id_val:res_box_textarea_id_val,res_owner_id_val:res_owner_id_val,res_src_id_val:res_src_id_val,sel_image_files:sel_image_files},function(data){
   ..}
```

my doubt is eventhough if i place both text inputs and file inputs inside the same form which i submit for file upload, how to report back for errors in file upload to the user ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty, but you could add a script tag to your iframe response. From there you could fire off some sort of warning or error message.

Comment: thanks johan . i can do something with this i guuess. it helps

Comment: What js lib are you using? I know for a fact that mootools can fire custom events. That would not even be that ugly.

Comment: Looks like you can user http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ to fire custom events in jquery. So just trigger a custom error event and add the error message as a parameter. You can catch this event in the main document using bind()

Comment: $(upload_iframe_id).load(function(){   alert($(upload_iframe_id).contents().find('body').html());
  }); - i did this to get the contents of the required iframe